# Writing valid XHTML textareas's? Cannot leave out rows & cols?

Tags: css, validation, xhtml, textarea

I try & write valid XHTML but I just checked some code & it is complaining of the "cols" & "rows" attributes being required when using textareas's?

Like anyone these days I would guess I am using CSS to set the width & height of them. Why do I need to use them? Can I just set them to blank?

```
<textarea rows="" cols="" ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cols and rows attribute are deemed required in the recommendations for [XTHML](http://www.w3.org/2007/07/xhtml-basic-ref.html#attr_cols) and [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7). Anyway, if you leave them out, they have default values (20 and 2 resp.)

Comment: You can leave them blank and they will pass Strict Doctype check. Make sure they are like this: `rows=" " cols=" " ` with a space between quotes. This just worked for me. FYI.